# What exactly does "this" mean in the context of Java threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, notify

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What’s the meaning for object’s monitor in java? Why use this word?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9848616/whats-the-meaning-for-objects-monitor-in-java-why-use-this-word)

In the java project I'm studying, I see this code block:

```
        // Continue once everybody is initialized
        if(allReady) {
            //AceFactory.log.fine("All ACEs are ready to start");
            readyAces.notify();
        }
    }
```

And readyAces is a  `Map<String, Boolean> AceFactory.readyAces` variable.

I look up what notify() does, and I see that it does the following:

> Wakes up a single thread that is waiting on this object's monitor. If
>   any threads are waiting on this object, one of them is chosen to be
>   awakened

But what is meant by "this object's monitor" ? thanks

Comment: Hint: look up `synchronized` and what it can be synchronized on and how. It uses "this object's monitor" as well.

Comment: Not *this* object but the object on which the monitor is done.

Comment: Exactly. It's *that* object. The same thing.

Comment: This is making my head feel stretched.. a good thing though./ thanks!

Comment: "Monitor" is simply the term used to refer to the internal data structure that is attached to an object that has any outstanding lock activity on it.  It's a bit more precise than saying "waiting on the object", but a bit more confusing as well.

Comment: @pst - I'm studying `synchronized` right now! thanks!