# What is a monitor and how is it implemented in JAVA?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, locking, monitor

How is a monitor and lock implemented in java, I know that the Object class provides us methods like `wait()` and `notify()` which control thread access, but at its core how is the monitor and lock implemented, like is there any specific resource or code that represents the monitor?

Comment: Partial answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9848616/whats-the-meaning-of-an-objects-monitor-in-java-why-use-this-word

Comment: For `wait()` and `notify()`: the method are implemented natively.

Comment: to add to @Turing85: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/lang/Object.java